# Copying Textures to other Objects; Ctrl+L not working

Tags: texturing

I have two objects. One I have applied a texture to. I want to copy that texture to another object.

Here is what I have tried:
Select the object I want to copy the texture to.
Shift+Select the object I want to copy the texture from. 
Ctrl+L ---> Materials

I got these instructions straight from Blender Stack. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Is the texture applied in the material or in UV Editor?

Comment: The texture is applied in the UV editor to the the first object only. I also tried marking the seams and unwrapping the second object which let me apply the texture. But still won't let me copy.

Comment: Ctrl+L will not copy textures from UV editor, you will have to link it from the image browser in UV editor in edit mode